# When using ant in eclipse, standard input does not work?

Tags: eclipse, ant

In `demo.Main.main` method I do

```
System.in.read()
```

In build.xml there is the target

```
 <target name="run">
    <java classname="demo.Main" fork="false">
      <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </java>
  </target>
```

When I go to Eclipse's Console and I give something in , `System.in.read()` does not see it.

Answer (score 1):

Ant does not support `System.in.read()`.

Use the [Ant task **`<input>`**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html) for user input instead.